# form-data in postman sending Empty body to nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I know this has been asked multiple times, but I have been looking around and still can't find an answer to my problem.

```
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config({
  path: ".env",
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const runDatabase = require("./config/database");
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())


app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "uploads")));

// routers
const userRouter = require("./router/usersRouter");
const categoryRouter = require("./router/categoryRouter");
const productRouter = require("./router/productRouter");

app.use("/api", userRouter);
app.use("/api", categoryRouter);
app.use("/api", productRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  runDatabase();
  console.log(`The Backend Server is up and running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Here is my code, when sending the request in JSON raw postman a response is what I need but when using a form-data it will return an empty body

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Try to add this to your middlewares. After express.json()

Comment: i have done what you asked me to do, but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Change `app.use('/', (req, res) => {` to `app.get('/', (req, res) => {`.

 `app.use` is intended for middleware, not normal requests.

 Read more about `app.use` and it's usages here: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

Comment: you don't get it, this issue is not what you thinking .. I asked for a problem on the response at controller  >> postman form-data return an empty body for me

Comment: I have tried both my or douscriptist's answers and they work. While douscriptist's may be more appropriate for you, you should provide information on how your using postman at this point based on your comment on douscriptist's answer.
Eg: Are you using GET ```localhost:PORT/```, have you verified that the port is open for local requests, have you verified that postman is not the issue (by using wget or curl), etc...